# Firefox shows outdated json data and chrome shows the correct one

Tags: firefox

Hey So I'm trying to design a gallery website, And I'm still a beginner 
so I'm working through these problems however this problem is really something that i've never seen

The file that loads up in firefox loads up json from a local server. 
I've modified the json file in the server but firefox however keeps showing me the same data over and over.

However the same file when opened in chrome opens up and shows me exactly what I want it to show

I'm quite baffled by this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is most likely caching the result from the server to reduce load times. Try clearing the browsers cache and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Hey, Thanks it worked but it looks like I need to keep erasing cache memory everytime I update my values is there someway around it

Comment: [Here's](https://dzone.com/articles/how-turn-firefox-browser-cache) a link that shows how to turn off the firefox cache for a site.

Comment: You can toggle the option for disabling the browser's cache while the dev tools are open. It's in the developer tools options. Very handy!